# AoC 2023 Day1P2: string.match returning empty strings when using ?=

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find groups that may start inside another match with regex (eg: find 'two' and 'one' in 'twone')

So far the regex that could get to work at regex101.com is `/(?=(one|two))/gm`.
The problem is that when I try to use this pattern in javascript it returns two empty arrays. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this for AoC? In my opinion it may be simpler to loop through each character and search the characters ahead.

Comment: Use [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to get all capturing groups of all matches

Comment: @Spectric Correct. I saw that as an opportunity to learn more about Regex but i cant figure this one out, maybe I'm missing something

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html: your expression may match at specific positions, but it does not match any content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) in addition to the [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```js
const str = `two1nine
eightwothree
abcone2threexyz
xtwone3four
4nineeightseven2
zoneight234
7pqrstsixteen`

const matches = str.split('\n').map(e => [...e.matchAll(/(?=(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|[0-9]))/g)].map(f => f[1]).join(''))
console.log(matches)
```

With this result the problem becomes quite trivial. Here is the full solution (spoiler alert):

```js
const str = `two1nine
    eightwothree
    abcone2threexyz
    xtwone3four
    4nineeightseven2
    zoneight234
    7pqrstsixteen`

const matches = str.split('\n').map(e => [...e.matchAll(/(?=(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|[0-9]))/g)].map(f => f[1]).join(''))

const numberForm = matches.map(e => e.replaceAll("one", 1).replaceAll("two", 2).replaceAll("three", 3).replaceAll("four", 4).replaceAll("five", 5).replaceAll("six", 6).replaceAll("seven", 7).replaceAll("eight", 8).replaceAll("nine", 9))
const numbers = numberForm.map(e => e[0] + e.slice(-1))
console.log(numbers)
```

Comment: "*full solution*" - to what? And how would this handle the case from the question, `twone`?

Comment: @Bergi OP is trying to solve a question for this year's Advent of Code.

Comment: Ah I didn't see the comment

Comment: Thanks! I tested with matchAll but was only looking at the first position of each iterator and it returns '' hence why I posted it here.  
In the example 'twone' the first value of the iterator results are [0] = '', [1]= 'two', could you explain why this happens?

Comment: @LéoDonato under the hood `matchAll` uses [`RegExp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec). The first value in the array is the matched text (which is empty, since we're using a lookahead) and the second item is the text captured by our capturing group.